# OpenAPI spec validation in Golang

Tags: go, specifications, openapi

I want to validate an openapi spec in a similar fashion as its done here : http://bigstickcarpet.com/swagger-parser/www/index.html but the difference is that Ill use GO to code the tool and its only a CLI.

I am trying to use this :

https://github.com/go-openapi/validate

But the main problem is that the documentation is almost non existent. I came here looking for help of someone that might previously used this library and can give me a MINIMAL example of sending a file containing a spec like such and having this library to throw all the errors or warnings in a similar fashion to the online Swagger validator.

I already can read a file and do some manual validation of the fields on it but of course thats not what I need to do and its just a sample.

Additionally, as a secondary question, I want to post this same question on their GitHub repo but I get this :

[image]

and I have no idea how to "review" these guidelines so I can post my question.

#### What I have :

```
func validate_spec(spec string) []validator_error {
    // RULES HERE. Now I am hardcoding since this is just a dummy app. On the real app we will need to use goapenapi plus a schema validator
    var errors []validator_error
    name_regex, _ := regexp.Compile("^[a-zA-Z]+[ ][a-zA-Z]+")

    // Validate _.name field
        if ( ! gjson.Get(spec, "name").Exists() ) {
            n := validator_error{Path: "_.name", Message: "Does not exist!"}
            errors = append(errors,n)
        }

        if gjson.Get(spec, "name").Exists() {
            if _, ok := gjson.Get(spec, "name").Value().(string); !ok {
                n := validator_error{Path: "_.name", Message: "should be a string"}
                errors = append(errors,n)
            }
            if ( ! name_regex.MatchString(gjson.Get(spec, "name").String() ) ) {
                n := validator_error{Path: "_.name", Message: "should match " + name_regex.String()}
                errors = append(errors,n)
            }
        }
    // ***************************

    // Validate _.age field
        if ( ! gjson.Get(spec, "age").Exists() ) {
            n := validator_error{Path: "_.age", Message: "Does not exist!"}
            errors = append(errors,n)
        }
        if gjson.Get(spec, "age").Exists() {
            if _, ok := gjson.Get(spec, "age").Value().(float64); !ok {
                n := validator_error{Path: "_.age", Message: "should be an int"}
                errors = append(errors,n)
            }

        }
    // ***************************
    return errors
}
```

#### What I need :

```
func validate_spec(spec string) []validator_error {
        // Something like this is what I am looking for. On the above example I am just hard-coding some dummy rules. I need to use the library here to get the validity of the spec being passed.
        return goopenapi.validate(spec )
    }
```

Comment: I have not used this library but the _test code, e.g. https://github.com/go-openapi/validate/blob/master/example_validator_test.go  is written at a higher level of abstraction than the above and looks worth modeling. Re: guidelines- these are here: https://github.com/go-openapi/validate/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md. These have more to do with submitting PRs than asking questions. Looks like they have a slack at: https://github.com/go-openapi/validate/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md, which might be a more fluid forum for asking questions.

Comment: Thanks Il take a look.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios Do you have any `swagger.json` file or this kind of any file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use https://github.com/go-openapi quite a lot and find that packages very useful to work with OpenAPI spec, validations and other related stuff.

### Validate the spec itself

Take a look at the following code:

```
document, err = loads.Spec(fpath)
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to load spec")
}

document, err = document.Expanded(&spec.ExpandOptions{RelativeBase: fpath})
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to expand spec")
}

if err := validate.Spec(document, strfmt.Default); err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "Spec is invalid")
}
```

First of all, it loads spec. Then it expands all references (`$ref`-s) in that spec. After that it validates the spec itself.

### Validate by spec

So the spec itself is correct. Now we want to validate, for example, a request body by that spec.

```
// sch here is the schema object that can be extracted from
// the spec that you created above.

// data is just an interface{} that represents your data
// structure that you need to validate. data is a struct
// you decoded a json body into like json.Unmarshal(b, &data)

err := validate.AgainstSchema(sch, data, strfmt.Default)
ve, ok := err.(*errors.CompositeError)

// now you can extract errors from ve.Errors
```

I've build [some wrappers](https://github.com/hypnoglow/oas2/blob/master/validate/validate.go#L14) around it for easy request validations, for example:

```
// op here is the OpenAPI operation object that can also be extracted
// from the spec loaded above.
if errs := validate.Body(op.Parameters, body); len(errs) > 0 {
    // work with errs
}
```

---

*Disclaimer: Some links above lead to the repository [oas2](https://github.com/hypnoglow/oas2) where I am an author and a maintainer. That repository is build on top of [go-openapi](https://github.com/go-openapi) where I am not the author.*

Comment: Thanks Ill give it a try.

Comment: I got my schema from here : https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/schemas/v2.0/schema.json But when I try to use it on your sample code, I get : Failed to expand spec
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference. What would that be? @hypnoglow

Comment: unfortunately, there is not full support for OpenAPI v3

Answer (score 4):

I've found that [kin-openapi](https://github.com/getkin/kin-openapi) provided the closest thing to the level of abstraction I was looking for. That is, I just want validate my http request and response against the spec, without breaking it into parts (query params, path params, body, etc). Its not *quite* to this level of abstraction, but I have an open PR. Not sure if it'll be accepted, but its a good starting point for your own adventures, nonetheless!

Comment: I see your PR was accepted https://github.com/getkin/kin-openapi/pull/197

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing @HairOfTheDog